# Is there an eval function for JSP EL?

Tags: jsp, eval, el

I'm looking for a way to evaluate a string as el when it is output in a JSP page. (i guess when it's toString() method is called under the hood???)

For example, in my page, if I do this:

```
<title>${bean.title}</title>
```

title will be a property of bean, which will return a string.  I'd like to store other EL expressions in bean.title so they are evaluated.

So, if bean.title = "`This is the ${param.pageType} page`", obviously that would evaluate before it was written to the page.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You're actually looking for the solution in the wrong direction. You should be using the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`fmt` taglib](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) for this. It supports [parameterized](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/param.html) messages as well. You should only change your code to store messages in an (internationalizable) `.properties` file instead of in the bean.

Assuming that you have the following key-value entry in the `text.properties` file which is placed in `com.example.i18n` package

```
title = This is the {0} page
```

then you can use it as follows

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.example.i18n.text" />
...
<title>
    <fmt:message key="title">
        <fmt:param value="${param.pageType}" />
    </fmt:message>
</title>
```

It adheres the rules of the [`MessageFormat` API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

#### See also:

- [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application) - a mini tutorial

Comment: hm - close. ResourceBundles work well for templated content, but in this case, I'm rendering content that comes from a CMS - well-structured content that contains arbitrary lists of things, etc. Also, since the naming of ResourceBundles is a convention based on their class name, I would be looking at a lot of ugly (slow?) reflection.  I will look to see if there is way I can use MessageFormat.  The first sticking point here is that MessageFormat relies on index/order rather than "keys".

Comment: You could also implement a custom `ResourceBundle` with a custom `Control` which you then put in the request scope using some `Filter` or `Servlet`. In the `Control` you can then load the bundle from the DB. You can find a basic example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499732/design-question-regarding-java-ee-entity-with-multiple-language-support/4500633#4500633 (just ignore the JSF tags and on, use the aforementioned filter/servlet approach which puts them in request scope and then use `${bundle.title}` and on.