# Multi language support in JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to create multi language web pages with database resource?

Instead of "messages_EN.properties", "messages_HU.properties", and so on... I'd like to keep those texts in database. Is it possible to use this in the same way as properties files? For instance #{messages.hello} would depend on the current users language, and the text would be loaded from database, not properties file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design question regarding Java EE entity with multiple language support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499732/design-question-regarding-java-ee-entity-with-multiple-language-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check this:

[Correct java.util.ResourceBundle Organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416375/correct-java-util-resourcebundle-organization)

The way to do it is described here:

[messages.properties taken from db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080474/messages-properties-taken-from-db)

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: Hi I know it, It happens that I just got the commentator role. Regards