# jstl and i18n: language selection and db

Tags: internationalization, jstl

I have to build a multi-language web site in JSP/Servlet.

I'm considering JSTL for the i18n, and I've some general questions:

1) is it possible to handle with jstl both the language selection by hand (e.g. through a pull-down menu or a link) and the automatic language recognition?

2) what is the better approach if the most part of strings are dynamic (retrieved from a database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *is it possible to handle with jstl both the language selection by hand (e.g. through a pull-down menu or a link) and the automatic language recognition?*

Yes. See also [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application).

---

> *what is the better approach if the most part of strings are dynamic (retrieved from a database)?*

You'd need to create a custom [`ResourceBundle.Control`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) which you inject in the request scope by a `Filter`. This filter should basically take over the job of `<fmt:setLocale>` and `<fmt:setBundle>`.

```
request.setAttribute("bundleName", yourCustomResourceBundle);
```

See also [internationalization in JSF with ResourceBundle entries which are loaded from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499732/design-question-regarding-java-ee-entity-with-multiple-language-support) (although JSF targeted, the idea is the same for plain JSP; as said, you'd only need a `Filter` instead to set it).

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. I've an error on your example in "How to internationalize a java web application", precisely in the option tag: Multiple annotations found at this line: - Invalid location of text (''}) in tag (<option>). - Invalid location of text (') in tag (<option>). - Invalid location of text (" ? ') in tag (<option>). - Undefined attribute name (en), etc. The strings "???login.label.username???:", "???login.label.password???:" and "???login.label.submit???:" appears instead of the corresponding values.