# How to use internationalization in JSF that retrieve the data from DB

Tags: database, jsf, jsf-2, internationalization

I want to use the standard internationalization from JSF (in property files )and the possibility to switch to database. Is it possible to replace JSF internationalization with own implementation that retrieve the data from DB, so I can configure it ? Or is in this case  another aproach better ?
I've found the following example: http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/ . In this example the own resource bundle class is defined. To use it only the reference in xml to implementation class is replaced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [internationalization in JSF with ResourceBundle entries which are loaded from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499732/internationalization-in-jsf-with-resourcebundle-entries-which-are-loaded-from-da)

Comment: Thank you for your help! The link is very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As BalusC pointed, you need to create a ResourceBundle and register it to the app or individually per page.

Simple example:

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="[helloworld]: #{msgs.helloworld}" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0">
   <application>
      <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>com.myproject.CustomResourceBundle</base-name>
         <var>msgs</var>
      </resource-bundle>
   </application>
</faces-config>
```

CustomResourceBundle.java

```
package com.myproject;

import java.util.ListResourceBundle;

public class CustomResourceBundle extends ListResourceBundle {   
    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return getMapOfWordsFromDatabase();
    }

    private Object[][] getMapOfWordsFromDatabase() {
        // TODO get key and words relation from database!
        return map;
    }
}
```

Theory:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaxv.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html