# JPA for Internationalization in JSF with ResourceBundle from DB

Tags: database, jsf, jpa, internationalization, resourcebundle

I've been using the method described in Stack Over Flow question [internationalization in JSF with ResourceBundle entries which are loaded from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499732/internationalization-in-jsf-with-resourcebundle-entries-which-are-loaded-from-da?answertab=active#tab-top). The problem I'm having is with JPA in the overridden `newBundle()` method in `DBControl` class.
When I use a named query to fill the `Map<String,String>` it gives a `missingResourceException`.
I then tried to build a resource class that extends `ListResourceBundle` inside the `DBControl` class and do the JPA there but it again throws the same exception.
Below is my code for more clarification:

```
protected class DBControl extends Control{
    @Override
    public ResourceBundle newBundle
            (String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException
    {            
        return new ArticleResources(locale);
    }       

    protected class ArticleResources extends ListResourceBundle{
        private Locale locale;

        public ArticleResources (Locale locale){
            this.locale = locale;
        }            
        String language = locale.getLanguage();

        @Override
        protected Object[][] getContents(){                  
            TypedQuery<ArticleLcl> query = em.createNamedQuery("ArticleLcl.findForLocale", ArticleLcl.class);
            query.setParameter("lang", language);
            List<ArticleLcl> articles = query.getResultList();
            Object[][] allArticles = new Object[articles.size()][3];                
            int i = 0;
            for(Iterator<ArticleLcl> it = articles.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
                ArticleLcl article = it.next();
                allArticles[i] = new Object[]{article.getArticleId().getArticleId().toString(),article.getArticleTitle()};
                messages.put(article.getArticleId().getArticleId().toString(),article.getArticleTitle());                    
                i++;
            }
            return allArticles;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: I figured out that my entity manager is always null and thus my query is not constructed and my list is not populated and hence the bundle cannot be found. Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because my resource bundle was only a POJO and not a managed bean and I could not inject using `@EJB`. I had to look it up using JNDI.
Here is the code:

```
try {            
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();            
            ArticleLclFacade arBean = (ArticleLclFacade) ctx.lookup("java:global/gtest/ArticleLclFacade");
            List<ArticleLcl> articles = arBean.getArticles(language);
            for(Iterator<ArticleLcl> it = articles.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
                ArticleLcl article = it.next();
                messages.put(article.getArId().getArId().toString(), article.getArTitle());                    
            }                    

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```